# How to change the position of label in frame using java

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have just started with making frames in java and wrote the following code :

```
 import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorldFrame extends JFrame

{       
  public static void main(String[] args)
{   
  new HelloWorldFrame(); 
}
HelloWorldFrame()
 {
    JLabel jlb=new JLabel("HelloWorld");  
    add(jlb);
    this.setSize(100,100);
    setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Can anyone help explaining how can I change the position of label in the above code

Comment: See [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/). It's all explained there. Hint: the default layout manager of JFrame's content pane is BorderLayout.

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with **layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly easy to change the position of your JLabel instance by using two methods which are really handing. Look below for the code to use :

```
HelloWorldFrame()
 {
    JLabel jlb=new JLabel("HelloWorld");  
    jlb.setHorizontalAlignment(50); // set the horizontal alignement on the x axis !
    jlb.setVerticalAlignment(50); // set the verticalalignement on the y axis !
    add(jlb);
    this.setSize(100,100);
    setVisible(true);
 }
```

You can learn more about JLabel and how to manipulate them here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html

//**EDITS**

Base on the comment that I've given earlier, the alignement that was given could not work. So I made the necessary changes to make them work !

```
 HelloWorldFrame()
     {
        JLabel jlb=new JLabel("HelloWorld");  
        jlb.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); // set the horizontal alignement on the x axis !
        jlb.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); // set the verticalalignement on the y axis !
        add(jlb);
        this.setSize(100,100);
        setVisible(true);
     }
```

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract I'm glad it did ! Continue to rock on on that java code !

Comment: but why am I getting the following warning during compilation now: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: horizontalAlignme
nt
        at javax.swing.JLabel.checkHorizontalKey(JLabel.java:607)
        at javax.swing.JLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.java:765)
        at HelloWorldFrame.<init>(HelloWorldFrame.java:13)
        at HelloWorldFrame.main(HelloWorldFrame.java:7)

Comment: This was an error of mine to provide you sample code like that. That's my fault. Just look the code on Oracle and as you can see "alignment - One of the following constants defined in SwingConstants: TOP, CENTER (the default), or BOTTOM."
You have a good example on how to use it here : http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node37.html

Comment: thanks finally got it displayed ,but I can't understand what is a swingconstant.

Comment: You can learn more about the SwingConstant interface here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html
You access it while importing the java swing implementation

Answer (score 2):

Usually (read recommended) what you are after is achieved through the use of [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). If that does not work for you, you would need to use [`setLocation(int x, int y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation(int,%20int)) and combine it with `this.setLayoutManager(null)` (or something like that). This will remove the default layout manager and give you complete control on where/how are your object placed.

EDIT: As outlined by @AndrewThompson, please go for the first approach rather than the second unless you really, really have to.

Comment: I did not think about that. That's better than using the alignment on the axis which means that the position would have been set already ! Nice answer

Comment: This horrendous advice again?  Please stop giving advice on making GUIs until your advice solves more problems *than it causes..*

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I'm not a big fan of the second approach myself. I did inform the OP which way is the recommended way. The OP did not specify any context I think both of them are valid answers, but as you say, the second approach will cause more trouble than it solves.